# Windows scrolling function distorts view

Tags: windows, scroll, windows-8.1

This isn't really related to coding or programming, but when I scroll in a Windows Application, such as Microsoft Word or Notepad++, the view becomes very distorted. Please refer to the preview below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuEXW.jpg

The problem has been occurring for several days now but was never an issue previously. It seems to occur in all text editors I use, seen in Microsoft Word in the above preview but also observed in Notepad++.

If someone has experienced similar issues or can advise me with this problem, I would be very grateful. System specs are as below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTviE.jpg

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: This seems to be an issue with my scrollpad. The problem does not occur if I scroll by dragging the scrollbar or if I scroll using a USB mouse with a scroll wheel. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think this could be anything from a possible Windows/Driver issue to even a hardware issue...

Comment: Have you tried using a different screen to see if the problem persists?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have another screen to check this but I have verified that the latest graphics driver is installed.

Comment: There could be a bug with the driver... did the problem start after the new driver was installed?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I think it is related to the scrollpad because the scrolling works fine if I just drag the scrollbar or use a USB mouse scroll wheel.

Comment: I have no idea where to start... Maybe you should mail Microsoft and see what they have to say on the matter?